# Как парсить внутреннее содержимое элемента html через JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Собственно есть статьи, которые представлены на ресурсе таким html:

```
<article class="day_news_item">
    <div class="day_news_item_img">
        <a href="/world/20151117/1322854695.html">
            <img src="http://cdn12.img22.ria.ru/images/132265/34/1322653488.jpg"
                 alt="Президент России Владимир Путин. Архивное фото"
                 title="Президент России Владимир Путин. Архивное фото"
                 width="230" height="130" class="media"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="day_news_item_text">
        <div class="day_news_item_title">
            <h3>
                <a href="/world/20151117/1322854695.html">Путин:
                    совместная работа Китая и России стабилизирует обстановку в мире</a>
            </h3></div><div class="day_news_item_announce">
        <a href="/world/20151117/1322854695.html">Сотрудничество
            России и Китайской Народной Республики двигается вперед в
            области военно-технического сотрудничества, что является
            серьезным фактором, стабилизирующим обстановку в мире,
            заявил президент РФ.
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

На одной странице их может быть много. Вот конструктор класса, объект которого мне нужно создать для каждой новости:

```
public News(String imgRef, String title, String text, String date, String announce) {
    this.imgRef = imgRef;
    this.title = title;
    this.text = text;
    this.date = date;
    this.announce = announce;
}
```

Вопрос: как это лучше всего сделать через JSoup?
Я не очень понимаю как нужно брать информацию из вложенных тегов и их атрибутов?

Надеюсь понятно сформулировал вопрос.
Спасибо!

Сохранил сайт wget-ом, зашел в его html и нашел там то самое содержимое которое мне и нужно ( и все его вложенные теги и атрибуты).

Еще им предшествовал вот такой скрипт:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() { checkBannerHeight(17); });</script></div></div><div xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" class="day_news"><div class="day_news_wrapper">
```

Возможно он должен мне указать способ получить данные с главной странице, не заходя по каждой ссылке в каждую новость отдельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Открываете документ, как написано, например, [тут](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) или [тут](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string)
2. Находите селекторы элементов, которые содержат нужные вам значения.
3. Берете нужные значения из аттрибутов или текстового значения.

Например так:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
String imgURL = doc.select(".day_news_item .day_news_item_img img").attr("src");
String title = doc.select(".day_news_item .day_news_item_title h3 a").text()
```

Если на странице новостей несколько, то находите список новостей

```
Elements newsElements = doc.select(".day_news_item");
```

Потом перебираете в цикле `newsElements` и для каждого элемента получаете, при помощи метода `select()`, нужные вам данные (как рассмотрено выше).

**Дополнено**

Сайт может отдавать страницу в другом виде (например посчитает ваше приложение за мобильный или вообще заблокирует скачивание). Чтобы хоть немного быть похожим на браузер нужно указать заголовок `User-Agent`. В *Jsoup* это можно сделать так:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.url").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

Если сайт будет защищаться активнее, придется придумывать что-то посложнее, но это уже догонялки оружия и средства защиты. В вашем случае наверное хватит и наличия заголовка `User-Agent`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но там такая сложность наметилась - текст объекта doc почему-то не содержит некоторых частей исходной веб страницы (если я смотрю код страницы через хром, эти элементы отображаются нормально) соответственно выдача нулевая. в чем может быть причина?

Comment: @АлександрДворцов Например потому, что часть контента генерируется скриптами. Нужно смотреть исходник HTML страницы и откуда скрипты берут контент. Для начала cкачайте страницу чем-нибудь без скриптов (wget, curl...) и посмотрите на ее сруктуру (или дополните вопрос).

Comment: Отредактировал исходный вопрос.

Там есть скрипт, который не похож на что-то берущее откуда-то контент. Может это строка сразу после него: xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" ?

Собственно джавовский doc.toString() дает ссылки на каждую новость, но не на их картинки и другие отображаемые свойства. Думаю решение с заходом по ссылке и парсинг уже страницы самой новости - не лучший вариант.

Comment: Посоветуйте хоть что почитать по теме! Совершенно не могу разобраться(

Comment: Могу посоветовать только документацию по _JSOUP_. А еще я зашел с пустым User-agent на ria.ru и обнаружил, что он непонятным браузерам возвращает урезанную страницу (видимо считают что это мобильный браузер). Дополню ответ

Comment: вот через html cleaner он видит классы вроде этого class="day_news_item".
В чем отличие html cleaner от jsoup в этом контексте?

Comment: Извините, я не в курсе что такое _html cleaner_

Comment: htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31768/discussion-between-tutankhamun-and--).