# Как получить доступ к содержиому HTML-тега с помощью Jsoup

Tags: java, html, парсер, jsoup

Не могу получить доступ к содержимому тега `datetime`(получить дату "12 апреля 2017"). Как это сделать при помощи Jsoup?

```
<a class="pub  " data-id="91846" data-ts="1491996396" href="/2017-04-12/muzey_istorii_ekaterinburga_ichet_oko_saurona_dlya_vodonapornoy_bashni_na_plotinke">

  <div class="pub-info">

    <span class="region">Екатеринбург</span>

    <time datetime="2017-04-12T11:26:36Z">12 Апреля 2017 16:26</time>

    <span class="comments" data-count="0">

      <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">

        <path d="M13.8 1.4c.4 0 .7.3.7.7v8c0 .4-.3.7-.7.7H7.5l-3.2 2.3v-2.2H2.2c-.4 0-.7-.3-.7-.7v-8c0-.4.3-.7.7-.7l11.6-.1m0-1.4H2.2C1 0 0 1 0 2.2v8c0 1.2 1 2.2 2.2 2.2h.7V16L8 12.4h5.8c1.2 0 2.2-1 2.2-2.2v-8C16 1 15 0 13.8 0z"></path></svg></span>

    <span class="likes" data-count="0">

      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">

        <path d="M12 9.229c.234-1.12 1.547-6.229 5.382-6.229 2.22 0 4.618 1.551 4.618 5.003 0 3.907-3.627 8.47-10 12.629-6.373-4.159-10-8.722-10-12.629 0-3.484 2.369-5.005 4.577-5.005 3.923 0 5.145 5.126 5.423 6.231zm-12-1.226c0 4.068 3.06 9.481 12 14.997 8.94-5.516 12-10.929 12-14.997 0-7.962-9.648-9.028-12-3.737-2.338-5.262-12-4.27-12 3.737z"></path></svg></span></div>

  <h5>Музей истории Екатеринбурга ищет «око Саурона» для Водонапорной башни на&nbsp;Плотинке</h5>
</a>
```

Comment: По этому и не можете получить, так-как, такого тега у вас нет, есть тег `time`, а `datetime` - это аттрибут, а не тег. Хорошо бы видеть код, который уже написали.

Comment: Извиняюсь, перепутал. Как раз доступ к содержимому `datetime` мне удалось получить, а вот содержимое тега `time` - нет. Я уже пытался получить к нему доступ на примере [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467136/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-html-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-jsoup/467141#467141), но ни один из вариантов кода не заработал.

Comment: А почему у вас в теге `a` завернуты блочные теги `div, h2`? Так делать ненужно. - это не правильно, в этом собственно может быть и проблема.